# Warning: Material-UI: the value provided `3` to the Tabs component is invalid. None of the Tabs children have this value

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I am using Material UI tabs and Reactjs, both are working fine visually but I realized while using Developer tools that there is an error every time I click on the last tab that I have
***Warning: Material-UI: the value provided `3` to the Tabs component is invalid. None of the Tabs children have this value. You can provide one of the following values: 0, 1, 2, 3.*** 
The tabs are generated in a dynamic way, have an array lie this:

```
const tabs = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'Information',
      component: <EventContaint />
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Attendees',
      component: 'Here attendees list',
      roles: { event: ['owner', 'organizer'] }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Committee',
      component: <EventCommittee />,
      roles: { event: ['owner'] }
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Schedule',
      component: <Schedule />,
      roles: { event: ['owner', 'organizer'] }
    }
  ];
```

After validating the roles the tab with the id 2 doesn't show (which is ok), but when i click on the Schedule tab the error appears (everything works fine, but I need help to fix this problem that appears on the console)

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  variant='scrollable'
  scrollButtons='on'
  indicatorColor='secondary'
  textColor='secondary'
>
  {tabs.map((tab, index) => (
    <TabWithRoles
      label={tab.title}
      {...a11yProps(index)}
      key={index}
      index={index}
      committee={committee}
      roles={tab.roles}
    />
  ))}
</Tabs>
```

The value and  handleChange are like this:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
  console.log('NEW_VALUE', newValue); // Schedules prints 3, but Committee is not rendered 
  setValue(newValue);
};
```

Comment: edit with   
value={value}
onChange={handleChange} 
what value does the variable value has, and the function handleChange funciton

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj I edited the post with the value and handleChange

Comment: seems tricky, I don't even know TabWithRoles component,  can you add your project there https://stackblitz.com/fork/react  and give me the link:), just add as much code so it can show the error and i will help you to fix it ;)

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj TabWithRoles is the Tab component of Material UI, but I added behaviour to this component through a HOC so this only renders when a user has a specified role on the application. Ok the project is getting complex, but maybe I can replicate the problem an upload it to stackblitz, thanks!!

Comment: when you upload it, comment here :) had some problems myself with something like this so i will help you

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj I've already uploaded the code, thanks for the help! I hope you find something

Comment: ahahhahahha where is the link

Comment: sorry is https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-w5owr9, TabWithRoles is on frontend/src/components/CustomTab